# How to get rid of too many arguments warning C4002 in cppwinrt header file

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt, winrt-component

I am getting a too many arguments warning in the following situation. I can report it as a bug but the repository in GitHub is closed and the cpp-winrt project is now owned by Microsoft.

> The situation
>   Create a new windows runtime component project using the cpp-winrt project template.
>   Add the macro "WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP" in the "preprocessor definitions" in c++->preprocessor section of the project settings.
>   Compile the project.

You will get the following warning:

…\generated files\winrt\impl\windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.0.h(4510): warning C4002: too many arguments for function-like macro invocation 'GetCurrentTime'

The line corresponding to the above message is "virtual int32_t __stdcall GetCurrentTime(int64_t*) noexcept = 0;"

Probably the name GetCurrentTime might be conflicting with the windows legacy API name!

Comment: To my knowledge, the C++/WinRT library does not include any Windows SDK header files. Are you including `<Windows.h>` (or others) in your code? C++/WinRT was moved into the xlang project a while ago. You can report issues [here](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/issues).

Comment: No, I removed everything and trimmed down the project to what is created by the WinRT/C++ template and added the macro definition. Created an issue in the xlang project as you mentioned: https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/issues/552

Comment: Worth noting that this error and workaround is called out in C++/WinRT documentation now:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/faq#how-do-i-resolve-ambiguities-with-getcurrenttime-and-or-try-

Answer (score 2):

GetCurrentTime is a known collision between a Windows.h macro definition and a WinRT member.  One solution is to #undef GetCurrentTime in your pch.h.

Comment: It is defined in winbase.h as follows:
`#pragma region Desktop Family  
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)  

#define GetCurrentTime()                GetTickCount()  

#endif /* WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP) */  
#pragma endregion`

Comment: Undefining it is not easy; especially conditionally.

Comment: The method is feasible, and it seems that there is only one solution at present.